# How do I interpret rally pace notes?

Tags: dirt-3

This applies probably much more broadly than to *DiRT 3* only, but what do all the pace notes my co-driver provides mean?  (Left|Right) [1-6]|"Hairpin" is easy enough to understand, along with the literal "keep left", "near house", but there are random numbers mixed in and other more abstract directions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general structure of pace notes is designed to inform the driver about the conditions of the course ahead in a shorthand fashion.

Most commonly they encode the distance to the next turn, the direction of the next turn, and the severity of the next turn.  So a pace note might be "100, 5 Left" - which might mean "100 meters ahead is a severity 5 turn to the left."  Higher severity in the [DiRT 3 pacenotes](http://community.codemasters.com/forum/dirt-3-general-discussion-1339/469281-pace-notes-what-does-left-three-exactly-mean.html) indicates that the turn is shallow, and can be taken at a higher speed/gear.

Pace note structure and format varies, as it's essentially a form of rapid-fire communication between the driver and co-driver.  Part of that is what's written on the page, and part of that is how the co-driver reads what's written.

Some [common elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacenotes) of [several systems](http://d24-rally.blogspot.com/2010/03/pace-notes-explained.html) I [researched](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jemba_Inertia_Notes_System):

- "Down" and "Up" for downhill and uphill
- Don't Cut or D/C - don't cut the corner, there's a hazard/dropoff.
- Flat - go full throttle, or flat out
- Square - a 90 degree bend (oversquare being more than 90 degrees)

If there's a specific term that's tripping you up, let me know and I'll try to find a specific reference for it.

Comment: There's also "crest" (small bump) and "jump". Which suddenly have a much clearer distinction when there's a corner after them. :p

Comment: Link is dead but I have [something useful](http://blog.codemasters.com/dirt/04/co-driver-calls-explained/).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't play dirt 3, but pacenotes are easy once you watch others use it. let's take a certain note and decode it:
100 R5
100 shows distance until turn
R5 shows turn and severity, R or L for right or left, and 1-6 for intensity 6 being almost straight to 1 being almost or a full u-turn
more codes can be found online, but these are basics